# startActivityForResult doesn't return to the same instance of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

I am using below code to take a photo from camera. I use `startActivityForResult` for the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent in my `CameraActivity` class. The camera can be open and it works fine to take a photo. But when it comes back to the `CameraActivity`, it goes into a different instance of `CameraActivity`. I am printing the hascode value in these two methods and it gives a different value. I don't understand why it creates two activities. Does anyone know this error?

```
public class CameraActivity  extends Activity{

private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_imageview);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());
        Bundle args = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)args.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Check your CameraActivity's launcher mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that system is destroying your activity for the time the camera application is working. When camera application is started, your app is in background so it is eligible for being destroyed. You can test it by adding logging to your onDestroy override.

Comment: I have tested and it works exactly as you said. How can I restore the activity after it destroyed? Shall I restore it from the savedInstanceState on onCreate() method?

Comment: @ZhaoYi yes, use savedInstaneState - for more information look here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState